# Is this lowest-leaf element the last in its branch?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given this XML fragment and XPATH/XSLT 1.0

```
<corpus>
    <TEI id="first">
    . 
    .
    .
    </TEI>
    <TEI id="second">
        <text>
           <div n="A">
              <div n="1" />
              <div n="2" />
           </div>
           <div n="B">
              <div n="3" />
              <div n="4" />
           </div>
        </text>
    </TEI>
    <TEI id="third">
    . 
    .
    . 
    </TEI>
</corpus>
```

When the current node is, say, n= 1, 2, 3 or 4, I need to know if it is the last `<div>` in its `<TEI>`.

I thought this would work

`test="node()=ancestor::TEI//div[not(div)][last()]"`

but to my surprise,

`ancestor::TEI//div[not(div)][last()]`

returns both elements 2 and 4, and

`ancestor::TEI//div[not(div)][last()][last()]`

does the same.

How do I test whether the current lowest-leaf `<div>` is the last lowest-leaf `<div>` in the current `<TEI>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression,

```
ancestor::TEI//div[not(div)][last()]
```

locates any leaf `<div>` element that is the last child of its parent.

This expression,

```
(ancestor::TEI//div[not(div)])[last()]
```

locates the last leaf `<div>` descendant of the TEI ancestor. This seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: (I removed those slashes. My mistake.)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks. +1, Q answered.